# rails compact writing of string slicing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

In my rails 4 app i use haml. and in view i write such string:

```
  %td= link_to admin_organization.introtext[0..40]+"...", admin_organization_type_organization_path(organization_type_id: admin_organization.organization_type_links.map { |e| e.organization_type_id }, id: admin_organization)
```

but when this field, "introtext" is empty, i get error and my app crash.

i know how to check it like:

```
-if admin_organization.introtext.present?
 blablabla
```

but this is long code. Maybe there are any other ways of doing this? Of writing string slice and check it if it's empty - that didn't dispay this link_to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`link_to_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) and for the slicing I would use the [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) text helper method:

```
%td= link_to_if admin_organization.introtext.present?, truncate(admin_organization.introtext, length: 40), admin_organization_type_organization_path(organization_type_id: admin_organization.organization_type_links.map(&:organization_type_id), id: admin_organization)
```

And on a side note: Are you sure you want to pass an array of IDs to `organization_type_id`? This doesn't seem to make much sense if you're using RESTful routes.